# C# Не запускается файл python, содержащий киррилицу в пути, в процессе командной строки

Tags: c#, python

Имеется небольшое WPF приложение, в функционал которого входит запуск скриптов на python. При запуске файлов не содержащих киррилицу в пути все проходит гладко, однако если в пути кириллица, python выдает ошибку:

```
C:\Users\The Bruno\source\repos\CommandExecutor\CommandExecutor\bin\Debug>
python "C:\Users\The Bruno\Desktop\ъюфsss\Python works\GUI_opener.py"

python: can't open file 'C:\Users\The Bruno\Desktop\╤К╤О╤Дsss\Python works\GUI_opener.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

При этом имя пути неправильно кодируется, можно ли как-то исправить, вот укороченный код:

```
public Process CmdProcess = new Process();

            ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");

            cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = SelfPath;

            cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            CmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
            CmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            CmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
            CmdProcess.Start();
            CmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            CmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        private void StartPyCommand()
        {
            CurrentFileName = EntryTextBox.Text;
            fullScan(SelfPath, CurrentFileName);//возвращает CurrentFileDir путь до дирректории файла

            CmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine($"python \"{$@"{CurrentFileDir}\{CurrentFileName}"}\"");

            CurrentFileDir = "";
        }

        private void cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if ((Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data))).StartsWith(@"C:\"))
                    //{ ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += $"[{EntryTextBox.Text}] >>> \n"; }
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                else
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                ConsoleScrollbarDiv.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }
        private void cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if ((Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data))).StartsWith(@"C:\"))
                    //{ ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += $"[{EntryTextBox.Text}] >>> \n"; }
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                else
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n";}
                ConsoleScrollbarDiv.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Интерпретатор Python нне понимает кодировку, с которой ОС создает директории.

Тут поможет только одно - создйте для скриптов папку без кирилических символов.

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема уже решена, кстати, решение все же есть, все решилось простым вводом команды `chcp 1251` в коммандную строку