# С# Закодировать строку так, чтобы при кодировании возвращала расшифрованный текст

Tags: c#

Имеется небольшое приложение, работающее как консоль. При отправке команды в консоль происходит кодировка, из-за чего python не может запустить файл, имеющий в названии кириллицу. Строка, отправляющаяся в консоль
подвергается кодированию в формат `CP866`. Как можно, так сказать, "прекодировать" эту строку так, чтобы при кодировке она декодировалась?

```
public Process CmdProcess = new Process();

            ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");

            cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = SelfPath;

            cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            CmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
            CmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            CmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
            CmdProcess.Start();
            CmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            CmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();


        private void SendEncodedToCmd(string input)
        {
            input = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetBytes(input));
            CmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
        }


        private void cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if ((Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data))).StartsWith(@"C:\"))
                    //{ ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += $"[{EntryTextBox.Text}] >>> \n"; }
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                else
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                ConsoleScrollbarDiv.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }
        private void cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if ((Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data))).StartsWith(@"C:\"))
                    //{ ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += $"[{EntryTextBox.Text}] >>> \n"; }
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n"; }
                else
                    { ConsoleOutTextBox.Text += Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(e.Data)) + "\n";}
                ConsoleScrollbarDiv.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }
```

При отправке пути, содержащего кириллицу происходит следующее:

```
C:\Users\The Bruno\source\repos\CommandExecutor\CommandExecutor\bin\Debug>python "\привет"
python: can't open file '\╨┐╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен. Попробуйте переформулировать, добавить больше деталей, примеров, ваших попыток решить вашу задачу.

Comment: уточнил  вопрос.

Comment: Возможно [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/c-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-python-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю здесь нужно смотреть в сторону объекта `Encoding` и работать с методами `"GetBytes()`" и "`GetString()`", причем `Encoding` отвечает за требуемую кодировку. К сожалению из вопроса не совсем понятно что нужно сделать.